# MSTSC crash on connect

Tags: windows-xp, rdp, terminal-server, mstsc

We are supporting a client with primarily Windows XP machines.  The users need to use Remote Desktop to connect to a terminal server.  Unfortunately, after upgrading to SP3 on some machines MSTSC.exe crashes when they try to connect to the terminal server (a Win 2008 machine).  The resolution I have found has been to revert to an older version of MSTSC as described here: http://it.tmod.pl/Blog/EntryId/115/Remote-Desktop-Connection-crashes.aspx .   Another tech at my company independently arrived at a similar solution.

Unfortunately, now some of the user's printers are missing (when connected tot he terminal server).  Has anyone else seen this issue?  How did you resolve it?

Comment: Rotard- Can you post the event log that corresponds with the crash? That will help pinpoint which module is faulting. Are you using a program called [triCerat Screwdrivers](http://www.tricerat.com/screwdrivers) by any chance?

Answer (score 6):

i had similar problem, try this:

1. remove content of C:\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Cache
2. log off, log on

don't ask why... it just did the trick for me.

Comment: Many thanks! This solved my seperate issue. Windows 7 client would RDP to non-NLA machines, but NLA machines would crash with "remote desktop connection has stopped working". Faulting module would be facredprov2.dll. Clearing this cache worked a treat.

Comment: You should get additional + for the "don't ask why" bit :)

Comment: Had the same issue on my Windows 7 Professional machine connecting to a Windows 10 Professional computer. Here is the corresponding folder in Windows 7: C:\Users\<Username>\Local Settings\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Cache

Answer (score 1):

I know this really doesn't solve the problem, but more works around it, but you may want to see this serverfault post. [Alternative Remote Desktop Software](https://serverfault.com/questions/5959/alternative-remote-desktop-software).

The only other thing I would do is rollback from SP3, I have heard other (all-be-it antidotal), stories of people not liking SP3 for various reasons. This however may not be an option.

Answer (score 1):

I found another answer to this! If you are trying to connect to any computer using Windows XP Remote Desktop and keep getting a crash error after clicking 'connect' this is the solution.

Run CCleaner!  Or run Disk Cleanup...

I spent about 2 hours on this issue, and after running CCleaner and disk cleanup I had NO ISSUES!! sorry to bring this thread back to life but this is the number 3 solution on google...

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem, however, I was able to pinpoint the cause.  It only happens if I log in to the remote computer with a thin client, then a thick client and back to the thin client.  I believe the problem is with the thin client somehow but I can't find any logs that indicate what happened during this crash.  My thin client is an HP t5710 running XPe.

Answer (score -1):

The issue has not come up again to my knowledge, but I think the problem may actually be a symptom of a greater problem: every (all of 2-3) machine that has exhibited this behavior has required a reformat in approximately a month or so of the time the mstsc problem surfaced.  So I think the standard procedure, if it comes up again, will be to just reformat