# Remote Desktop of multiple servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

what is the name of the program that allows you to switch between servers (using Remote Desktop Connection) with a mouse click?

The program had a list of servers on the left pane and the main pane was the actual server connection.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Have a look at my question on this: http://serverfault.com/questions/5959/alternative-remote-desktop-software

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're talking about the Remote Desktops MMC snapin

[image: Remote Desktops]
<sub>(source: [qainsight.net](http://www1.qainsight.net:8080/content/binary/MMC_RemoteDesktop.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I think the OP was looking for the built-in remote desktop manager and not a 3rd party product like I had originally thought. =)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. How do I start it?

Comment: What OS are you running? Have installed the admin tools?

Comment: Windows Vista SP1. I installed this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D647A60B-63FD-4AC5-9243-BD3C497D2BC5&amp;displaylang=en&displaylang=en
Now what?

Comment: I think you can get them by installing the Remote Server Administration Tools for your OS (Vista, 7, etc)

Comment: Start | Run | MMC.exe | File | Add Snap In | Scroll down to Remote Desktops | Add | Ok | Add a bunch of servers | Save the console somewhere

Comment: I had to turn windows features on or off. Found it. Thanks...

Answer (score 7):

Late to the party, but so is this option: Microsoft's own RDCMan (Remote Desktop Connection Manager) is a huge upgrade to their old MMC snap-in.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21101

Highly recommended.

[image: Sample RDCMan]

Image from [Introducing Remote Desktop Connection Manager (RDCMan)](https://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/06/11/3410093.aspx).

Comment: If I could +1 this more, I would.

Comment: I love rdcman. The fact that it can store different TS gateway settings for different groups is just a lifesaver.

Comment: I love it, very nice!

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, use [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/) for that. Supports RDP, VNC, telnet, http/s and a bunch more.
[Royal TS](http://www.code4ward.net/main/) is another worth looking at.

Comment: Beat me by two seconds!!! =)

Comment: Why install 3rd party apps when MS provides a snapin to to the job?

Comment: For me? Because I like an "all-in-one" that does more than just RDP. I have one tool (mRemote in my case) managing all my RDP, VNC, web (iLO2 and such) and SSH connections. It makes me happy :-)

Comment: i have trouble getting mRemote to work with some Server 2008 systems.  im so annoyed.

Comment: @djangofan - as mentioned in the answer to your question about this, the trouble with alternative RDP clients and 2k8 servers is likely that they're requiring NLA. Turn that off or make it optional and I'm fairly certain that it'll start working.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows machines:

- [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/) (Abandoned Open-Source project -- still solid. Codebase was merged with the following closed source product)
- [VisionApp Remote Desktop](http://www.thincomputing.net/blog/visionapp-remote-desktop-1.5-vrd-1.5.html)
- [MuRD](http://murd.tandksoftware.com/)
- [Terminals](http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals) (Open source project that doesn't have a whole lot of activity... could use some TLC, but it still works)

Comment: Why install 3rd party apps when MS provides a snapin to to the job?

Comment: As per Chris_K's comment to your comment I like the all-in-one approach. However, from just an RDP standpoint, Microsoft's MMC snap-in is bad at managing large numbers of connections. You can't have inheritance to aid in the creation and management of multiple connections, there is no centralized connection store (SQL backend, for instance) and you can't save different sets of credentials to use for one connection. To name a few things.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Terminals](http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals) for a while now, use it for RDP, putty and web management pages.

I have all my "native" work in the left screen most of the time and save the right screen for terminals and server / management work.

Works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

[Terminals](http://terminals.codeplex.com/).  It recently had an update released.

Answer (score 1):

The item you need is in the [Windows Server 2003 Administration Tools Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c16ae515-c8f4-47ef-a1e4-a8dcbacff8e3&displaylang=en)

If you install it I think you'll find what you need.