# Is it possible to increase the size of mstsc's connection cache

Tags: mstsc

On my windows box mstsc.exe caches the last ten hosts I connected to. However, I connect to about 15 on a regular basis, so increasing the number that the combobox remembers would be really welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I've ever seen, it seems to be a hardcoded limit in the client.  The MRU list is stored in `HKCU\Software\microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default` and adding multiple values to that key does not increase the size of the list in the client UI.

There are other packages out there that let you manage connections, though.  Maybe have a go at one of them.  Have a look at [**this question**](https://serverfault.com/questions/5959/alternative-remote-desktop-software) I posted a while back.  I personally like mRemoteNG.